# How to mimic WinForm anchors in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Using Silverlight, I have a button in which I'd like to add two TextBlock: one completely centered in its parent container and another one in the bottom-right corner of its parent container (see picture below). In good old WinForms, it would have been easy to use anchors to achieve this. However, using the limited number of containers of Silverlight, I am unable to achieve the same results.

Any idea or suggestion on how to achieve this? I am trying to come up with the right container for this and a way to make sure that everything is perfectly aligned.

Please note that the text can be longer than 1 character and the X and 0 can slightly overlap (in other words, I couldn't use a 3 row grid).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack elements on top of each other in a Grid like so:

```
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="X" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="0" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

***EDIT***

This example uses a custom button style to achieve the posted result:

```
    <Button Width="200" Height="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" Background="White" Padding="16">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="X" FontSize="144" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="SteelBlue" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="SteelBlue" />
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This seem to work! By any chance, do you know how to force the Grid to fill the parent container (in my case a button)?

Comment: You can set Horizontal/Vertical ContentAlignment on the Button to Stretch and/or Horizontal/Vertical Alignment to Stretch on the child elements.  But you shouldn't have to as by default those properties are set to Stretch.  Also make sure you don't have Padding or Margin pushing the contents in.  I updated my example with a button style that comes pretty close to your screen shot and with all the default button states removed.  You can get the default Silverlight control templates here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you Rob! I had completely forgotten to update the HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment of the button! You just turned my hacky solution into an elegant one! Thanks!